# Need to change below code to get first day of last month(July 1st,2016) and first day of current month (Aug 1st,2106)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Need to change below code to get first day of last month(July 1st,2016) and first day of current :

```
DECLARE @StartDate  as Date = (SELECT cast(Dateadd(D, -(day(getdate()) - 1), getdate()) as date))
DECLARE @EndDate    as Date = (SELECT dateadd(M,1,cast(Dateadd(D, -(day(getdate()) - 1), getdate()) as date)))
 DECLARE @EndDate2  as Date = (SELECT cast(getdate() as date))
```

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

First get the first date of the month of the current month, then use that value to get the first date of the month of the one prior:

```
DECLARE @Current DATE = CAST(DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,GETDATE()),0) AS DATE)

DECLARE @Prior DATE = CAST(DATEADD(MM,-1,@Current) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Did try the above and got the following error:                                               Must declare the scalar variable "@Current".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 40
Must declare the scalar variable "@EndDate"

Comment: There is something else wrong with your code that is causing that. Post the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first two lines in your code from:

```
DECLARE @StartDate  as Date = (SELECT cast(Dateadd(D, -(day(getdate()) - 1), getdate()) as date))
DECLARE @EndDate    as Date = (SELECT dateadd(M,1,cast(Dateadd(D, -(day(getdate()) - 1), getdate()) as date)))
```

to:

```
DECLARE @StartDate as Date = (SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())-1, 0));
DECLARE @EndDate as Date = (SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()), 0));
```

Explanation:

`DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()), 0)` gets the difference in months between epoch and the current date. `DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()), 0))` simply adds those number of months back to epoch again.

Comment: tried the above but resulting quesr has incorrect values. My activation dates appear to be blank which it shouldn't be

Comment: As per the question you've asked, I've gotten the first dates of the current and previous months into `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`. If it's still not giving you the desired output, you should probably raise another question. Do you have valid data in `WPYUSData.sdldim.Partners` and `WPYUSData.sdldim.MerchantChannels` falling within the required date range?

Comment: Yes there is valid data in both the tables you mentionedIt should pull all the data   beginning from july1st and less than august1st

Comment: Okay, you'll need to break up the query. Firstly `NULLIF(ISNULL(Signing_Date, '9999-01-01'), '9999-01-01')` is the same as using `Signing_Date`. Secondly run the query `select * from WPYUSData.sdldim.Partners where Partner_Category = 'Strategic Partners' and  p.Signing_Date between '01-Jul-2016' and '01-Aug-2016'` and tell me if it returns anything.

Comment: hey the code worked all I had to was swap the DECLARE @StartDate=(SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())-1, 0));

Comment: Okay...changing that in my answer above as well.